# what is edible, vegan, and is slimy like a raw egg?

Tags: egg-substitutes, eggs

What can be used as an egg substitute in veggie burgers and other recipes?

I read the following:

> to make one flax egg mix 1 Taablespoon flaxseed meal + 3 Tbsp water.

What else works?

Comment: Have you tried wheat gluten? We used to use pure gluten for veggie burgers but now use ground TVP and add gluten as a binder.

Answer (score 1):

I find that [aquafaba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquafaba) works great as a binder for patties.

I cook a lot of garbanzo beans, so I'm always filling jars of aquafaba and storing them in the fridge. It's an ingredient that most would just throw away, but it works great as an egg replacer to hold patties together.

Answer (score 1):

In reality, egg can be used for many different recipes and uses. We probably find eggs in many recipes because they were developed around the common things - things we have at disposal easily.

However, to replace egg with a vegan substitute, we use different ingredients depending on the use, meal/recipe we are making.

The table below is an example of the possible replacements:

| Category | Substitute | Amount replacing 1 egg | Common uses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Baking (binding) | Applesauce | 1/4 cup | Muffins, cakes, brownies |
|  | Mashed banana | 1/4 cup | Pancakes, muffins, cookies |
|  | Pumpkin puree | 1/4 cup | Breads, muffins, cakes |
|  | Silken tofu | 1/4 cup | Brownies, custards, quiches |
|  | Yogurt (non-dairy) | 1/4 cup | Cakes, muffins, quick breads |
| Baking (leavening) | Baking powder + vinegar | 1 tsp baking powder + 1 tbsp vinegar | Cakes, quick breads, pancakes |
|  | Baking soda + vinegar | 1 tsp baking soda + 1 tbsp vinegar | Cakes, muffins, cookies |
| Baking (moisture) | Vegan buttermilk | 1 cup non-dairy milk + 1 tbsp vinegar/lemon juice | Pancakes, waffles, muffins |
| Cooking (binding) | Flaxseed or chia Seed | 1 tbsp ground + 3 tbsp water | Veggie burgers, meatloaf |
|  | Commercial egg replacer | See package instructions | Baking, pancakes, waffles |
| Cooking (texture) | Silken tofu (blended) | 1/4 cup | Scrambles, quiches, omelets |
|  | Chickpea flour | 3 tbsp | Frittatas, omelets, savoury dishes |
|  | Arrowroot powder | 2 tbsp | Thickening sauces, gravies |
|  | Potato starch | 2 tbsp | Thickening sauces, soups |
|  | Cornstarch | 2 tbsp | Thickening sauces, custards |
|  | Agar-agar | 1 tbsp | Puddings, custards, jellies |
| Binding & leavening | Chickpea flour + water | 2 tbsp chickpea flour + 2 tbsp water | Pancakes, waffles, baked goods |
| Binding & moisture | Mashed avocado | 1/4 cup | Baking, desserts, chocolate mousse |
|  | Nut butters | 1/4 cup | Baking, cookies, energy bars |
|  | Unflavored vegan yogurt | 1/4 cup | Baking, pancakes, waffles |
|  | Aquafaba (chickpea brine) | 3 tbsp | Meringues, mousses, marshmallow fluff |